# How do you split a "Cartesian task" into blocks?

Tags: apache-spark

Lets' say we have an RDD of input files. After we analyze (a long and expensive process) them, they become large items that need to be compared, for instance, each items is about a gig in size. We want to split this task using Spark and we have about a 1000 or more items like this. How do we go about doing this?

basically, the question is, if we have `N=1000+` items and each weighs `Size=1000MB+` then how do we go about splitting this into blocks of 10 or so, and spliting the work on Spark?